# Mysql Multiple Left join logic

Tags: left-join

Can someone explain multiple left join logic?
For example i have 3 tables: Company, company_text, company_rank.
Company has 4 records (id's: 1,2,3,4), company_text has 4 records with company names (1-a,2-b,3-c, 4-d), company_rank has following (1-1st, 2-2nd, 3-3rd). Note that company_rank table is not having 4th record. Now i want records of all companies using LEFT join. In case if there is no rank, display as 'zzzz' and sort in the descending order of rank and when rank is null sort by descending order of id.

```
select * from company
LEFT JOIN company_text ON company.id = company_text.id
LEFT JOIN company_rank ON company_text.id = company_rank.id
order by isnull(company_rank.rank,'zzzz'), rank desc
```

Will this work?

Basically i am trying to understand how LEFT JOIN works if there are many left joins? This doc. has good info on joins: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html but it don't have information on  how multiple LEFT JOINS work? In case if multiple joins are present, how records data will be pulled?

Comment: Same as with any other JOIN. You just join them one by one, as if it is a new table, that's all...

Comment: Your query doesn't make any practical sense though because id's of different tables are completely unrelated. You want to join on the shared fields (i.e., company.id = company_text.company_id or something along the lines)

Comment: can someone explain how multiple joins work? 
select * from table 1 
left join table2 ON xxxx
left join table 3 ON xxxx
Will it left join table2 and table3 or table1 and table3?

Comment: You will join a result of join of table1 and table2.